# How to set element's width according the text inside?

Tags: css, html, angularjs

I use CSS speech bubble (http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/)
in order to implement a chat.

This is an example of screen I ended up with:

[image]

The blue bubble is a message from me and the red is from a counterpart.

The piece of code I wrote is:

```
<p class="inset list" ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'id'"
ng:class="{ true:'triangle-right right', false:'triangle-right left'}
[message.sender == {{ user }} ]">
{[{ message.body}]}
</p>
```

while {[{ }]} is a symbol of angular parameter.

**I would like that the width of the bubble will be fit to the length of the text inside.**
Please pay attention that the message inside one bubble may include several rows so the width needs to fit to the longest row.

**In addition, the blue bubbles need to be alignment to the right.**

I tried to insert function for ng-style as function of *message.body* but I didn't succeed to make the width changed as I wanted...

It would be very kind if one of you can write me detailed and implicit instructions...

Comment: Show HTML, and CSS, that reproduces the situation you're working with. Ideally *also* (***not 'instead'***) show a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would float: left and clear: right, and vice versa

Comment: Hi David, what is missing? Is there a lack of data to clarify my question? I have a lot of irrelevant code there...

Comment: Tim, what does it mean?

Comment: @Lior what styles are in, for example the classes: triangle-right and right?

Comment: @Tim, these classes are from "CSS speech bubble" I used - http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: You can see the default styles here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/default.css

Comment: right geedubb... but the point is how to set the width of the element to be proportional to the text inside...

Comment: i understand the problem I was posting the link for info

Comment: @Lior http://jsfiddle.net/K67NN/ that is what I meant

Comment: @Lior http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/ and that is basically what David Thomas was talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/K67NN/1/

[image: jsfiddle screenshot]

this is my test html:

```
<p class="triangle-right left">test1</p>
<p class="triangle-right right">test2</p>
```

I used the stock css that you linked to, and I just added these to the classes left and right

```
.left{float:left; clear:both}
.right {float:right; clear:both}
```

This works because floated elements have implicit width by default and they are aligned to the left or right of their enclosing element. The `clear:both` just keeps them from piling up on one line.